# odoo 403 Forbidden error on web shop product

Tags: permissions, odoo, http-status-code-403, access-rights

Whenever I a product in the web shop with another user than Admin, or with no user (public) I get the 403 Forbidden Error screen and following error in console:

> QWebException: ('AccessError', 'No value found for product.template(6,).attribute_line_ids')

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Some thing got deleted

Comment: you are facing AccessError  so either use sudo or just set 1,0,0,0 for public user  in the security file